# It is Possible to pass value along with table column in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Basically,

## 1.I have all data as dynamic data from the database including the table header columns and I used it in ng-repeat.

[image]

The table column header from the database and I used **ng-repeat="l in labels"**. And for the select dropdown I used **ng-repeat="e in excelvalues"**

**This is my html.**

```
<table class="table">

<thead>
<th ng-repeat="l in labels"><div style="width:200px;"></div>{{l.labelname_en}}</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<td ng-repeat="e in excelvalues"><select class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedExcel" ng-options="excel for excel in excelvalues" ng-change="change(selectedExcel,$index)"></select></td>
</tbody>

</table>
```

## 2.I need to add the selected values in the array one by one with the table header column.

*For example* - If I selected a values in first dropdown it will add in the array with column name(Risk Description) and

I want the json like

```
[{"Risk Description":"1st selected Value"},{"Probability":"2nd selected Value"}....]
```

I don't know how to achieve this. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: provide json properly

Comment: I just posted on the sample json.

Comment: Give us more information like examples of 'excelvalues', list of each label select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/kczmyrtj/1/) which is made as I understood your intent by using `ng-repeat`.

If you wanna give feedback about what you want, I'll try that.

```
<thead>
    <th ng-repeat="l in labels" style="width:50px; text-align:center;">
        {{l.labelname_en}}
    </th>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in excelvalues">
        <td ng-repeat="l in labels">
            <select ng-model="e[l.labelname_en]" 
                    ng-options="opt as opt for opt in l.label_opt">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```